# Drag and drop no longer working on my drupal 7 site after workbench acess install

Tags: workbench

When I enable the workbench access module, all drag and drop reordering is broken. It doesn't work under blocks or under the menus. This doesn't happen on my local computer.

The working bench acess module I have is 7.x-1.2 under drupal 7.28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got fixed by installing the speedy module which compreses all the js.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting a newer (or older) version of jQuery using "jQuery Update"

Comment: That doesnt solve the problem.  Neither does uninstalling the workbench access module

Comment: Hi Diana, did you try clearing the cache after updating jQuery?  I've had this exact issue with another module, not workbench, ie a problem with drag and drop.  If it is a problem with workbench, then uninstallng it should have cured the problem.  Even more likely your cache needs clearing.

Comment: yes cleared the cache several times .  didnt solve the problem